# EAGLE. Differential pair routing. Width of the track changes after first change of direction

Tags: eaglecad, wire, differential, routing

I try to route differential pair of tracks. When I click the mouse to change the direction it also changes the width

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You start with current width of wires and after placing or changing direction eagle switches to width set in net classes.